# Where to wire the neutral wire?

Tags: blower, motor

I recently had to replace my fan blower motor and not sure where to wire up the l1 white wire for the neutral I have it on the breaker and the fan will not turn off continuously blows

Comment: Needs *much* more detail. Please edit to include a complete description of what equipment you are trying to connect to what, and what wires and terminals are present on each.

Comment: You *did* make some kind of record of how the previous fan blower motor was connected, didn't you?

Comment: Why do you have the neutral wire on the breaker?